# Why is it お[腹]{なか}が[空]{す}いた but [腹]{はら}[減]{へ}った?

Tags: word-choice, set-phrases, onomatopoeia, metaphor

Is there any particular reason why the noun おなか goes with verb すく while the noun はら goes with the verb へる? Would it be weird if I use おなかへった or はらすいた?

While on the same topic, does the 'starving' onomatopoeia ペコペコ go with both おなか and はら?

Comment: Just by the absence of particle in 腹減った, you could see that is much more colloquial. In fact, I only heard "young" guys use it. That might explain the difference or lack of consistency.

Comment: @Lukman: Are you sure you mean [tag:onomatopoeia] and not [tag:mimetics]? Does "pekopeko" represent the sound of a tummy grumbling or the feeling of hunger? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_sound_symbolism)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides the phrases being idiomatic (fixed), there is a slight difference in the meaning of these words.

```
お腹 (onaka) means stomach, although it can also mean belly
腹 (hara) means belly
```

You can also tell this from the fact that the pronunciation for `お腹` (onaka) is related to `中` (naka) 'inside', which implicates stomach. Therefore, even with the same predicate, they mean different things:

```
お腹が痛い 'my stomach hurts' means stomach ache caused by eating too much or poisoned food
腹が痛い 'my belly hurts' means laughing to death, (in addition to the meaning above)
```

In the case in the question, `空く`　'become empty' goes well with stomach rather than belly. `へる`　'lose volume' goes well with belly rather than with stomach (stomach is just a wall).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a regional thing, but お腹減った [おなかへった] isn't weird at all.  In fact, I hear and use it a lot.  On the other hand, 腹空いた [はらすいた] sounds weird and I don't think I've ever heard it before.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know who told you that each only went with one, but I don't think that's true.

I have most definitely heard お腹【おなか】used with both verbs. And Google seems to agree (100ks hits for either).

腹【はら】is less common in any case, and 腹空いた【はらすいた】 sounds a little unusual, but Google still gives over 60k results for it, so I doubt it could be considered 'rare'.

ペコペコ describes your feeling of hunger (among other things), not the particular emptiness of your stomach/belly, so no reason to use it with either word.

Comment: 腹がペコペコ and おなか(が)ペコペコ are usual expressions, although they may sound a little childish.