# "must have been" construction

Tags: grammar, translation, particles

Passage in question:

> よっぽど　おなかが　**すいて　いたんだなあ**。

As I understand, the translation is something along the lines of "You must have been very hungry." My problem lies within the bold text: how exactly each element of this passage is constructed? Dictionaries and rikaikun didn't quite help and I also don't know whether there are any kanji in the passage (although I doubt it) since I encountered it in a children's cartoon with kana-only subtitles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **空【す】く**: (consonant-stem, intransitive, "instant state-change" verb) "to become empty/vacant".
- **お腹【おなか】が空く【すく】** : (verbal set expression) "to become hungry". See: [Why is it お[腹]{なか}が[空]{す}いた but [腹]{はら}[減]{へ}った?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1630/5010)
- **お腹が空いて**: Te-form of お腹が空く.
- **お腹が空いている**: "to be hungry". See [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010) and [Difference between お腹がすいた and お腹がすいている ― 「お腹がすいた」と「お腹がすいている」の違いは？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21576/5010)
- **お腹が空いていた**: Ta-form (past form) of お腹が空いている. "to have been hungry".
- **んだ**: =のだ. "It is that ～." This is known as explanatory の. See: [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- **なあ**: Just another sentence-final particle to show exclamation.

So the super-literal translation of お腹が空いていたんだなあ would be something like "Oh, it is that your stomach had become empty."

Comment: Thank you so much! I have suspected that it was a part of a verb, but apparently there is a typo in source material (すて instead of すいて) and it really threw me off.